# Angular json convert to instance of object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application where I want to convert a json to an array in Angular.
The map is done correctly, however, my data is not an instance of my object, thus, any methods/functions that I created in that class cannot be called.
Here is the code I am using

```
export class Armor {
name: string;
listOfUpgradeMaterials: Material[];

get externalLink(): string {
    return this.name.replace(" ", "_");
}
```

And here is how I am converting

```
 // result is a Json value with a array of armor
 var list = <Armor[]>result;
 console.log(list[0].externalLink); //does not work
 console.log(list[0].name);//works
```

I tried using a custom map, but if I do that, my children property 'Material' does not get instanciated, so it does not work either

```
this.list = _.map(this.list).map(function (x) {
let armor: Armor = Object.assign(new Armor, x);
return armor;
});
```

What is the overall solution to handle this even with multiple level objects?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using this keyword eg :  this.list[0].externalLink

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(result.json());`? It's not clear where `result` came from.

Comment: Is `list[0]` an object with a `name` attribute? I'm not entirely sure how type assertion works, but I would expect `list.externalLink` to work, but not `list[0].externalLink` since the latter is a different object and not an `Armor` object. If this is the case then if you replace `name: string;` with `banana: string;` I would expect `list[0].banana` to fail in the same way `externalLink` does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate classes with `new` operator for using getters/setters/methods. I suggest to make definition of fields in constructor like:

**1)**

```
export class Armor {
  constructor(public name: string,
              public listOfUpgradeMaterials: Material[]){}

  get externalLink(): string {
      return this.name.replace(" ", "_");
  }
}
```

And you can use next code for instantiating:

```
...
this.list = result.map( item => {
  const { name, listOfUpgradeMaterials } = item;
  const materials = listOfUpgradeMaterials.map(material => new Material(material));

  return new Armor(name, materials);
} )
...
```

**2)**
Or another way - you can use `Object.assign`, but for both Armor and Material objects

```
...
function instantiate(item, clazz){
  return Object.assign(new clazz(), item);
}
...
this.list = result.map( item => {
  item.listOfUpgradeMaterials = item.listOfUpgradeMaterials
    .map(material => instantiate(material, Material));
  return instantiate(item, Armor);
} )
...
```

**3)**
Also if you cant want to separate all properties like `new Armor(name, materials, ...)`, you can assign fields in constructor and transfer there the object

```
export class Armor {
  public name: string,
  public listOfUpgradeMaterials: Material[]

  constructor(armor: Armor){
    Object.assign(this, armor);
  }

  get externalLink(): string {
      return this.name.replace(" ", "_");
  }
}
```

After that you can using `new Armor(armorJSON)` instantiating (but you also need to instantiate both Material and Armor objects)